getting the latest date for a a duplicated item in r
I have the following dataset (below).
I am trying to get the latest SEnd value for each individual tag (see Desired output) where I have the Tag, Owner and the latest SEnd date only. Essentially I am getting the latest year for SEnd.
I have tried the following. Is there a function I could use to order these and remove the items not needed and keep the unique and latest SEnd.
latest_dates <- merged_df %>%  
group_by(Tag) %>%
arrange(desc(merged_df$`SEnd`)) %>%
top_n(1) %>%
select(`SEnd`)




Tag
Date
Time
Name
SEnd
Owner




10GS3
06/14/2015
01:00:00 am
LATITUDE E7250
2018
Show


10GS3
06/14/2015
01:00:00 am
LATITUDE E7250
2018
Chris


10GS3
06/14/2015
01:00:00 am
LATITUDE E7250
2020
Show


10GS3
06/14/2015
01:00:00 am
LATITUDE E7250
2020
Chris


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
Patrick O C


12268
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
None


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
Patrcik O C


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
Patrick O C


12268
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
None


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
Patrcik O C


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
Patrick O C


12268
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
None


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2021
Patrcik O C


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2025
Patrick O C


12268
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2025
None



Desired output



Tag
Date
Time
Name
SEnd
Owner




10GS3
06/14/2015
01:00:00 am
LATITUDE E7250
2020
Chris


12267
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2025
Patrick O C


12268
09/24/2020
12:00:00 am
LATITUDE 5410
2025
None




Provide reproducible data dput(merged_df).

In you desired output you have included ties for 12267 but picked only one record for 10GS3 while there are ties for this one as well (2 records with 10GS3, 2020). So why/how there 3, not 2 or 4 rows in desired result?

Thanks @margusl I've updated it now, I had the Tag incorrect, it should be 3 lines

There actually is a function for this, dplyr::slice_max() can be instructed to ignore ties (i.e. duplicate SEnd values), it allows you to set a grouping variable and a column that would be used for ordering, all in one go:
merged_df |> 
  dplyr::slice_max(order_by = SEnd, by = Tag, with_ties = FALSE) |> 
  dplyr::select(Tag, SEnd)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Tag    SEnd
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 10GS3  2020
#> 2 12267  2025
#> 3 12268  2025

Input data:
merged_df <- 
  readr::read_csv("Tag,Date,Time,Name,SEnd,Owner
10GS3,06/14/2015,01:00:00,LATITUDE E7250,2018,Show
10GS3,06/14/2015,01:00:00,LATITUDE E7250,2018,Chris
10GS3,06/14/2015,01:00:00,LATITUDE E7250,2020,Show
10GS3,06/14/2015,01:00:00,LATITUDE E7250,2020,Chris
12267,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,Patrick O C
12268,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,None
12267,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,Patrcik O C
12267,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,Patrick O C
12268,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,None
12267,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,Patrcik O C
12267,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,Patrick O C
12268,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,None
12267,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2021,Patrcik O C
12267,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2025,Patrick O C
12268,09/24/2020,00:00:00,LATITUDE 5410,2025,None")
#> Rows: 15 Columns: 6
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (4): Tag, Date, Name, Owner
#> dbl  (1): SEnd
#> time (1): Time
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.


Thanks for your help, use slice max as I could pull all the columns though and keep the data.  I was trying slice max but I couldn't get it working correctly. I really appreciate the help.

One-liner with base R
aggregate(SEnd ~ Tag, merged_df, max)

Tag SEnd
1 10GS3 2020
2 12267 2025
3 12268 2025


I used merged_df <- read.delim("clipboard") after copy of your table.
